# .NET Core 3.0 migration error IAsyncEnumerable<T> exists in both System.Interactive.Async and System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to migrate a project from .net core 2.2 to 3.0.

I am getting the error:

> Error CS0433  The type 'IAsyncEnumerable< T >' exists in both
>   'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0

I tried one suggestion here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15047 which suggests forcefully updating to System.Interactive.Async  4.0.0.  (I added this reference to my project).

However I have another error:
Reference to type 'IAsyncEnumerable<>' claims it is defined in 'System.Interactive.Async', but it could not be found

I am using IAsyncQueryProvider and it seems that it is causing the issue.

I did not have these issues in 2.2, and I currently could not find any workaround.

I also tried forceably updating to System.Runtime 4.3.1 which did not help.

Comment: That issue was for an old preview version. I can't reproduce any problem with EF Core 3 in a .NET Core 3.0 project. Have you upgraded EF Core to 3.0?

Comment: Yes your suggestion worked.  In fact I did not upgrade to EF Core 3.0, I added it,  it seems I did not need this reference in .NET CORE 2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggestion from Panatiotis works,  I added the reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0 and it worked.  This reference was not needed in .NET Core 2.2 for my situation.

Answer (score 10):

As one who stumbled upon this on .NET Core 2.2 but wasn't migrating to 3+, I found another solution on the [same issue referenced above](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14239#issuecomment-451590181).
Project file referenced was modified since this comment, so [here's a direct link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/4bd1884bc6e2b7330766e1a192912f0371166fac/Directory.Build.targets#L9).

In my case I added this target to project file:

```
<Target Name="AddAssemblyAliasToReactiveAsync"
        AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
        Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.2'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition=" '%(FileName)' == 'System.Interactive.Async' ">
      <Aliases>reactive</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: my interaction was with Microsoft.bcl.asyncInterfaces and System.Interactive.Async.  In my case, I wanted Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, so that is what I used in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question has been answered, I've found here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14239 a person that had a similar problem to this one and almost identical to mine.

The netcoreapp3.1 project using EntityFrameworkCore (3.1.1) and IAsyncEnumerable interface.
My build ended with this error:

```
error CS0433: The type 'IAsyncEnumerable' exists in both 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

The problem was caused by using nuget restore command (not dotnet restore) and I had an old version of nuget.exe. Upgrading to the latest nuget.exe fixed the build.

Comment: thanks for this, it was the solution that i needed :)